# Using SOAP vs cUrl with unusable function names

Tags: php, curl, soap, soap-client

there is a SOAP webserver that I have to call to use in my application.

Using `__getFunctions()` I see a list of fuctions (27 of them) and with `__getTypes()` I see a list of structures (47 of them)

The functions have weird names, like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => UNKNOWN XYZ.AB.01.RC.GetThingRe(UNKNOWN $body)
    [...]
    [27] => UNKNOWN XYZ.AB.12.RC.GetThingSt(UNKNOWN $body)
)
```

So I'm really lost on how I'm supposed to call them.

I tried:

```
$SOAP->XYZ.AB.01.RC.GetThingRe($body);
```

and also

```
$SOAP->__call('XYZ.AB.01.RC.GetThingRe', Array($body));
```

but none of them work. I'm doing something wrong? It's a problem of the wsdl?

How am I supposed to make use of the structures:

```
Array
(
    [0] => struct GetThingRequestType {
 string Thing1;
 string Thing2;
 string Thing3;
 string Thing4;
 string Thing5;
 string Thing6;
}
```

and how I'm supposed to know which structure must be used with which fucntion?

As a workaround I've used cUrl to make calls to service, I build the xml structures manually and handle the responses. Everything works, but I don't know if this is bad practice, and if the performances are better or worse than properly use SOAP.